# How to implement an interface in C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, interface, implementation

I have an assignment and trying to understand something. I have an instruction to create two interfaces: `IComparable` and `IPrintable`. Also, I need to create a template called `Interval`.

I am given the `main` function and I need to implement these classes accordingly so it will work as intended.

This is the function I am currently implementing (the comments displays what the input should look like):

```
void testDate() {
    Date independence(14, 5, 1948);

    cout << independence << endl;

    Date otherDate = independence;

    cout << "Independence:" << independence << ", Other: " << otherDate << endl; // Independence:14/05/1948, Other: 14/05/1948
    otherDate.setMonth(2);
    cout << "Other date: " << otherDate << endl; // Other date: 14/02/1948
    otherDate.setDay(29);
    cout << "Other date: " << otherDate << endl; // Other date: 29/02/1948
    otherDate.setYear(1947);
    cout << "Other date: " << otherDate << endl; // Other date: Not a leap year

    otherDate = Date(24, 1, 1959);
    cout << "Other date: " << otherDate << endl; // Other date: 24/01/1959

    cout << "Comparing using polymorphism" << endl; // Comparing using polymorphism
    IComparable<Date> *indP = dynamic_cast <IComparable<Date> *> (&independence); 

/* --------------------------- ^^^ Stuck in the line above ^^^ --------------------------- */

    cout << "Is independence <= otherDate ? " << (*indP <= otherDate) << endl; // Is independence <= otherDate ? true

    IComparable<Date> *otherP = dynamic_cast <IComparable<Date> *> (&otherDate);
    cout << "Is other date <= independence ? " << (*otherP <= independence) << endl; // Is other date <= independence ? false

}
```

If you will look at code, you can see where I am stuck and that's my problem:
As far as I know, this type of writing is using templates. But in the instructions, `IComparable` is said to be an interface and not a template.

How can I implement this using an interface? Can I implement it using an interface?

This is my Date.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Date.h"
#include "IComparable.h"

using namespace std;

void Date::setDay(int d) { day = d; }
int Date::getDay()  const { return day; }
void Date::setMonth(int m) { month = m; }
int Date::getMonth() const { return month; }
void Date::setYear(int y) { year = y; }
int Date::getYear() const { return year; }

Date::Date(int d, int m, int y) {
    setDay(d);
    setMonth(m);
    setYear(y);
}

void Date::operator= (const Date& other) {
    day = other.getDay();
    month = other.getMonth();
    year = other.getYear();
}

void Date::toOs(ostream& output) const {
    // TODO : Check if leap year!
    output << getDay() << "/" << getMonth() << "/" << getYear();
}

bool Date::isLeapYear(int yearToCheck) const {
    if (yearToCheck % 4 == 0)
    {
        if (yearToCheck % 100 == 0)
        {
            if (yearToCheck % 400 == 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: An interface defines one or more pure virtual methods which your class needs to implement. An interface may or may not use templates (probably more often. they do not). So you need to define the classes `IComparable` and `IPrintable ` and then derive from these and implement these functions in your concrete class. Read up on "C++ interfaces" and "virtual base class".

Comment: A [mcve] would be very helpful, since the important parts of the code have not been included, and lots of irrelevant code has been provided.

Comment: I can't think of any situation where those `dynamic_cast`s would make any sense. The code will only work if `Date` derives from `IComparable<Date>`, in which case any cast is unnecessary.

Comment: A `dynamic_cast` generally never makes sense on a pointer to a stack value. Even for the very few reasons you'd want to have a value of pointer-to-base-type, you can use `static_cast`.

Comment: which part of the code was given to you and which part did you write?

Answer (score 2):

#### What doesn't work ?

Let's evacuate your line issue: You do not need [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) to implement polymorphism.  `dynamic_cast` should only be used in very specific cases. And the cast to succeed, it requires some inheritance relations between the source and target types (here `Date` and `IComparable<Date>`).  Unfortunately, without the class definitions and the error message, it's not possible to advise further.

#### What is an interface ?

You are right: `IComparable<Date>` is a template, and not an interface.

Interfaces are not a C++ language feature.  But there is a common understanding about what it is: it's a class with no functionality that is meant to promise a bahavior that will be implemented by other classes.  The C++ standard describes it this way (in a foot note, so it's indicative only):

> An abstract class can also be used to define an interface for which derived classes provide a variety of implementations

The functions have to be virtual to get the polymorphic behavior. Abstract classes are furthermore classes that have pure virtual functions (i.e. functions that are not defined) and that can therefore never be implemented directly.

#### Next steps ?

The general idea would be:

```
 class IComparable {
 public:  
    virtual bool is_equal(const IComparable &a, const IComparable &b) = 0;  
    virtual bool is_lesser(const IComparable &a, const IComparable &b) = 0;  
    ... // whetever else you want
    virtual ~IComparable(){};    // good practice: one virtual function -> virtual destructor
 };
```

You could then let `Date` implement it:

```
class Date : public IComparable {
public:
    bool is_equal(const IComparable &a, const IComparable &b) override; 
    ... // you SHOULD override all the pure virtual of the interface
};
```